# How to insert list of items into URL, Python

Tags: python, for-loop, meraki-api

I am trying to insert network ID's, which are located on a per line basis in a text document. There are about 500 lines of ID's. For each network ID, I need to insert it into an existing URL. The function of this is to query the names of network names associated with the ID in Meraki.

I am not fluent in python but here is what I have so far.
Where the %s is located, that is where I need each network from the text file inserted into the URL. This one runs, but only returns the very last line in the text document.

```
import requests, meraki, json, os

with open('Test.txt') as file1:
 file = file1.readlines()
 for line in file:
         url = 'https://dashboard.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/%s' %line.rstrip("\n")
         payload = None
         headers = {'X-Cisco-Meraki-API-Key': 'API_Key','Content-Type': "application/json"}
         response = requests.request('GET', url, headers = headers, data = payload, allow_redirects=True, timeout = 10)
         print(response.text)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)

```
base_url = "https://api.meraki.com/api/v0/networks/"
with open('PATH/TO/DOC','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        network_id = line.strip() #modify the line manipulation as req'd
        request_url = f"{base_url}{network_id}"
        ...
        # rest of your code
```

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: @JoshS Could you provide more details, beyond 'did not work'?

Comment: It simply did not produce any output. Updated code currently being ran in original message. Just need each item from list placed where %s is in the URL.